# how to add item in Spinner Android

Tags: android, spinner

How to add item from str in spinner? I tryed with ArrayList, ArrayAdapter but didn't work...

```
String[] str={"item 1","item 2","item 3"}; 
Spinner s=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use simple default ArrayAdapter to achieve your requirement dynamically. Below is the code snippet you can follow and modify your onCreate Method to add values in the spinner.

```
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    List<String> list;

    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Item 1");
    list.add("Item 2");
    list.add("Item 3");
    list.add("Item 4");
    list.add("Item 5");
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

if you want the spinner values to be added statically you can add the array in the xml file and assign the attribute `entries` for the spinner. below is the code snippet for that.

**Your layout xml file**

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"                  
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:prompt="@string/spin"
    android:entries="@array/items" />
```

**In your arrays.xml file**

```
<string-array name="items">
    <item>Item 1</item>
    <item>Item 2</item>
    <item>Item 3</item>
    <item>Item 4</item>
    <item>Item 5</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: This code doesn't work

Comment: @DacSaunders Ok!!!

Answer (score 2):

The Android reference has a good example and instead of using:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

as given in the example (this is because the `Spinner` is populated from a pre-existing string-array resource defined in an xml file ) you could use the `ArrayAdapter` constructor that accepts a List as its argument, as shown at:

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29

You could do this like so:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.your_layout,mYourList)
```

where mYourList could be an `ArrayList<String>` where you can store the data that you want to populate your `Spinner` with.

Answer (score 1):

Android `Spinner`s use the `SpinnerAdapter` class.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html